# Day/Date/Time/Temperature Info bar

Tags: javascript, datetime, temperature

Thanks for looking at my question.

I am looking to have a London information bar on a website. Something that will show the following information:

London, England: 9:27PM Friday 12 February 10°C/50°F

Can anyone please help?

Thanks :)

TO LET ALL KNOW, I DO JUST WANT IT FOR LONDON. NO MATTER WHERE YOU ARE VIEWING IT FROM. NOTHING MORE COMPLICATED

:D

Comment: you wanna do this with java or javascript ?

Comment: javascript, that was an accidental tag, I assumed javascript would come before java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In looking into this a little recently I came upon this [IBM developerWorks page about XML processing](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/xml/library/x-xmlajaxpt1/index.html), describing 4 approaches to this sort of problem.  However, unless you can access a server to either store the data or serve as a proxy, the last approach (using JSON and an intermediate (Yahoo in this case) service for the weather info, documented in [Part 3](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/xml/library/x-xmlajaxpt3/)) is probably best.

Answer (score 0):

The [Yahoo Weather API](http://developer.yahoo.com/weather/) is a well documented API for obtaining weather information.

Comment: But that is for RSS. How can I put that to a regular page? Thanks :)

Comment: There are a number of ways.  http://dtsn.co.uk/2009/11/26/javascript-weather/ contains an example using JSON and Yahoo Pipes.

Comment: Thanks Place. I have no experience of this. Do you possibly have a simple example? Thanks :)